# DataGridView selected cell style

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I change the "selection style" on a DataGridView (winforms)?

Comment: Clarified my question. I meant: change the _whole_ looks (style, background included) of a cell that _is_ selected, _when_ it is selected. There is no point to change the style of it if you never see the visual change. I'm deeply sorry for the misunderstanding :-(. My poor english strikes again. sorry )-:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily change the forecolor and backcolor of selcted cells by assigning values to the SelectedBackColor and SelectedForeColor of the Grid's DefaultCellStyle.

If you need to do any further styling you you need to handle the SelectionChanged event

Edit: (Other code sample had errors, adjusting for multiple selected cells [as in fullrowselect])

```
using System.Drawing.Font;

private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in ((DataGridView)sender).SelectedCells)
        {
            cell.Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle()
            {
                BackColor = Color.White,
                Font = new Font("Tahoma", 8F),
                ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText,
                SelectionBackColor = Color.Red,
                SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText
            };
        }
        }
```

Comment: SelectedBackColor, SelectedForeColor OK. It seems there is no way to set different colors for differents cells. :-(

Comment: SelectedBackColor and SelectedForeColor when used on the DefaultCellStyle property will apply the same colors to any selected cell.  
If you want to set a style to different cells, once again the answer is to handle the SelectionChanged event and do some conditional assignment based on the row or the column of the selected cell.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SelectedCells property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx) of the GridView and the [Style property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.style.aspx) of the DataGridViewCell.

Comment: no good. Tested with a DataGridView on an empty form using this code (only changes the first selected cell):

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Beige;
}

The style is only visible after the selection is changed to another cell.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the SelectionChanged event on your DataGridView and add code that looks something like this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell c in row.Cells)
            {
                c.Style = this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle;
            }
        }


        DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        style.Font = new Font("Courier New", 14.4f, FontStyle.Bold);
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            cell.Style = style;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Tested. Incomplete. The background isn't applied, while the font is. Weird

Comment: The background IS applies, but the color of the "Selection" is overriding it. If you double click in the cell to edit, you'll see the background color.

Answer (score 1):

With this you can even draw a colored border to the selected cells.

```
private void dataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected == true)
        {
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);
            using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 1))
            {
                Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
                rect.Width -= 2;
                rect.Height -= 2;
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rect);
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution provided in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178421/how-do-i-change-the-datagridview-selected-row-background-color). I've tested and approved it.

Hope that helped.