# How do I change the datagridview selected row background color?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How do I change the datagridview selected row background color in C# windows applications?

Comment: You need to add more detail to the question, perhaps post some code and what you have tried and what failed. Your question as it stands is not answerable.

Answer (score 55):

Come on man... there has to be a simple solution, and finally got one.

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Red;
```

This worked for me, no complex codes, no event handling. I did it before but was not able to recall so thought posting it would help others  and me in future :)

Answer (score 34):

On the DataGridView there is a `DefaultCellStyle`, inside this there is `SelectionBackColor` and `SelectionForeColor` properties.

The DataGridView uses a style inheritance idea, in case you find that the style you pick is not being applied:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This is the simple and working version that you can copy and paste:

```cs
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as DataGridView).CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Comment: this is what i really looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Taking advantage of `DataGridViewCell`'s events `CellEnter` and `CellLeave` you might try something like this:

```
private void foobarDataGridView_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridViewCellStyle fooCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
  fooCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
  this.VariableFinderDataGridView.CurrentCell.Style.ApplyStyle(fooCellStyle);
}

private void foobarFinderDataGridView_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridViewCellStyle barCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
  barCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
  this.VariableFinderDataGridView.CurrentCell.Style.ApplyStyle(barCellStyle);
}
```

Comment: What if the row color before selection was not white?

Comment: I mean that was just a quick sample to illustrate the concept -- you just create a helper method to retrieve whatever color you need to toggle there.

Answer (score 3):

The color can be changed also in the designer of a 'DataGridView'

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: Nice one Adam!  I never knew that existed!!