# Change highlight color of Data Grid View

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

We have a data grid view. If we select a column header, all cells in the column will be highlighted in blue color.  We need to change the color of the selected column header to yellow, and prevent highlighting other cells in a column.

How can we do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the datagridview selected row background color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178421/how-do-i-change-the-datagridview-selected-row-background-color)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.aspx):

Try something like this:

```
dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black;
```

Answer (score 1):

For changing the columns header;

```
dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

also try to set the `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` flag to `False`. But I don't any idea to prevent highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

// Set dataGridView to handle only full column selection.

```
this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode =
DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect;
this.dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
```

// Grab the index of the column selected :-

```
var index = this.dataGridView1.SelectedColumns[0].Index;
```

// Set the ForeCOlor & Back Color.

```
dataGridView1.Columns[index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
dataGridView1.Columns[index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
       dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    }
```