# change the background color a selected row datagridview

Tags: c#

In my datagridview, if I click on cell, background selected color of an entire row should get changed. Please guide me to do this.

Comment: You have not invested any effort into researching this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Usae the `DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor` 
Alternativly you can see [NanoTaboada answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3239597/395659)

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code, I think it might help:

```
dgv.Rows[curRowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. I tried the below, it worked.

```
dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
```

Comment: If one of the answers helped you to get what you want I would sugest you 'accept' that answer, as a thank you for their effort.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle event RowStateChanged of DataGridView and set SelectionBackColor.
Try code below :

```
 DataGVEmployee.RowStateChanged += new DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventHandler(DataGVEmployee_RowStateChanged);



    void DataGVEmployee_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
     if (e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
                {
                    e.Row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;

                }
}
```