# Datagrid row background color change on double click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I'm trying to change the color of wpf datagridview selected row when user double click on the row. Can someone please give me a sample code?

Comment: try datagrid's `MouseDoubleClick` event

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor, for example:

dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Red;

Check these out:

[change the background color a selected row datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642816/change-the-background-color-a-selected-row-datagridview)

[How do I change the datagridview selected row background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178421/how-do-i-change-the-datagridview-selected-row-background-color)

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to the **MouseDoubleClick** event of the datagrid view & change the color in it.

Sample code:

```
myDataGridView.MouseDoubleClick += dgvMouseDoubleClick;

private void dgvMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    myDataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Aqua; 
}
```