# How to change the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkbox selection background color?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I'm using a DataGridView in a Windows Forms application in which I use DataGridViewCheckBoxColumns. The problem is that they have a standard selection backcolor which I can't seem to change. What I mean is the blue color in the checkboxes as can be seen in the image below.

[image]

I have tried to change the color like this (while looping trough the DataGridViewColumns in the initialization of the DataGridView):

```
if (col.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn))
{
    col.CellTemplate.Style.SelectionBackColor = WinFormsUITheme.styleColor;
    col.CellTemplate.Style.SelectionForeColor = WinFormsUITheme.styleColor;
}
```

But this doesn't work. How should this color be changed? Or is this not possible?
Is there maybe a way to change the standard windows selection highlight color for a whole Windows forms project? Or maybe this should be done in the DataGridViewCellPainting event?

Comment: isnt it defined at row-level ?

Comment: Ok so you have to do this in the DataGridViewCellPainting event?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the datagridview selected row background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178421/how-do-i-change-the-datagridview-selected-row-background-color)

Comment: Well that is about changing the selection back color of the selected row. That does not change the checkbox selection background color. No this is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, your goal is to have control over the selection back color and possibly the color of the fill on the checkboxes themselves.

[image: custom colors]

This snippet manipulates the `DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor` of the entire DGV but you can override this for an individual cell using its `Style` property, or for a single column using the column's`DefaultCellStyle`. So, if this is all you need to do, you don't necessarily have to custom paint at all.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Disposed += (sender, e) => Provider.Dispose();
    foreach (var radio in tableLayoutPanelRadios.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
    {
        radio.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            switch (radio.Name)
            {
                case nameof(radioNone):     // <= Used in `CellPainting` handler for e.PaintBackground.
                case nameof(radioDefault):
                    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0x78, 0xd7);
                    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.White;
                    break;
                case nameof(radioYellow):
                    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

Your comment mentions the `CellPainting` event and one decent way to handle it is by drawing a unicode text glyph. For example, the custom glyph font **checkbox-icons.ttf** used in the above screenshot was made on [Fontello](http://www.fontello.com), set as an embedded resource, and loaded using the utility extension shown below.

[image: fontello]

---

**MainForm**

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    .
    .
    .
    FontFamily CheckBoxFont { get; } = "checkbox-icons".LoadFamilyFromEmbeddedFont();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = Recordset;
            dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView.CellPainting += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkbox)
                {
                    if(dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].IsInEditMode == true)
                    {
                        dataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                    }
                    e.Handled = true;
                    e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, false);
                    using (var glyphFont = new Font(CheckBoxFont, dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font.Size + 1))
                    using (var sf = new StringFormat
                    {
                        Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                        LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                    })
                    {
                        Brush brush;   
                        switch (dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
                        { 
                            // Use a static brush (doesn't require dispose)
                            case nameof(DemoRecordClass.IsGreen): brush = Brushes.Green; break;
                            case nameof(DemoRecordClass.IsBlue): brush = Brushes.Blue; break;
                            case nameof(DemoRecordClass.IsRed): brush = Brushes.Red; break;
                            default:
                                return;
                        }
                        var glyph = e.Value is bool isChecked && isChecked ? "\uE801" : "\uE800";
                        e.Graphics?.DrawString(glyph, glyphFont, brush, e.CellBounds, sf);
                    }
                }
            };
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView.Columns)
            {
                col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            }
            Recordset.Add(new DemoRecordClass{ IsGreen = true, IsRed = true, });
            Recordset.Add(new DemoRecordClass{ IsBlue= true, });
        }
    }
    BindingList<DemoRecordClass> Recordset { get; } = new BindingList<DemoRecordClass>();
}
```

---

###### Example Record Class

```cs
class DemoRecordClass
{
    static int count = 1;
    public string Name { get; set; } = $"Item {count++}";
    public bool IsGreen { get;set; }
    public bool IsBlue { get;set; }
    public bool IsRed { get;set; }
}
```

---

###### Font loading utility

```cs
public static class Provider
{
    public static FontFamily LoadFamilyFromEmbeddedFont(this string ttf)
    {
        var asm = typeof(Provider).Assembly;
#if DEBUG
        var names = asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
        { }
#endif
        var fontFamily = privateFontCollection.Families.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Name.Equals(ttf));
        if (fontFamily == null)
        {
            var resourceName = asm.GetManifestResourceNames().FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Contains(ttf));
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourceName))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Expecting font file is embedded resource.");
            }
            else
            {
                // Get the embedded font resource stream
                using (Stream fontStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)!)
                {
                    if (fontStream == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Font resource '{resourceName}' not found.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Load the font into the PrivateFontCollection
                        byte[] fontData = new byte[fontStream.Length];
                        fontStream.Read(fontData, 0, (int)fontStream.Length);

                        IntPtr fontPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontData.Length);
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, fontPtr, fontData.Length);
                        privateFontCollection.AddMemoryFont(fontPtr, fontData.Length);

                        fontFamily = privateFontCollection.Families.First(_ => _.Name.Equals(ttf));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {   /* G T K */
            // Already loaded
        }
        return fontFamily;
    }
    public static void Dispose() => privateFontCollection?.Dispose();
    private static PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection { get; } = new PrivateFontCollection();
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/data-grid-view-checkbox-color.git)

Comment: Thank you (also for the GitHub repository)! Interesting solution.

Comment: Oh for sure. And I think I did a better reading of your actual question this morning and made changes accordingly. Styles in DGV are overlaid on a property-by-property basis. If there's no individual `cell.Style` value it goes to the column or row style, and if that value isn't defined it falls to the `DefaultCellStyle` of the DGV itself. Repo updated, too.